# Why this function to change relative number in lines is not working?

Tags: line-numbers

I have found this very useful function to turn on and off relative number lines:

```
function! NumberToggle()
  if(&relativenumber == 1)
    set number
  else
    set relativenumber
  endif
endfunc
```

but it doesn't work, when I launch it

```
:call NumberToggle()
```

I see no changes, even when I close and reopen vim.

The source of the function is [here](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2012/relative-line-numbers-in-vim-for-super-fast-movement/) with other useful related tricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intention of the function as described in the blog post is *not* to toggle `relativenumber` but to switch between the `number` and `relativenumber` settings.

In Vim 7.3, the `number` and `relativenumber` settings could not be used at the same time, and I believe setting one automatically unset the other.

However, as of Vim 7.4, you can enable both settings at the same time. Doing so will use the absolute line number for the current line, and relative line numbers for all other lines.

If you don't wish to do this, and do in fact want to switch between using relative line numbers everywhere or absolute line numbers everywhere, you can amend the function accordingly:

```
function! NumberToggle()
  if(&relativenumber == 1)
    set number
    set norelativenumber
  else
    set nonumber
    set relativenumber
  endif
endfunc
```

Alternatively, you could just leave `number` on at all times, and just toggle `relativenumber`, which, as [grodzik has explained](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10433/343), you can do with a simple: `set relativenumber!`. This will switch between displaying absolute line numbers everywhere, and displaying it only on the current line (with relative numbers elsewere).

Comment: I think this explains best what is going on in the function. I would advise Three Diag to read the Vim help on 'number' for an example of what each option does. Generally speaking the Vim help is a good place for finding answers.

Answer (score 7):

Why won't you use Vim's builtin feature to toggle that? Just use: `set relativenumber!` - this will cycle between on and off.

Comment: I want to bind it as suggested in the link, as `nnoremap <C-n> :call NumberToggle()<cr>` can I do that with `:set ... !` ?

Comment: Yet, shouldn't the above work too? What's amiss with it?

Comment: It doesn't turn anything off, and toggle should at some point do that. `number` and `relativenumber` aren't excluding each other, and I think that was the assumption here. When you set `relativenumber`, you get relative numbers with current line being `0`. When you add to that `:set number` you still will have relative numbers, but current line will be marked with actual number of current line in a buffer.

Comment: In other words, replace "set number" with "set norelativenumber".

Comment: That assumption might be true for Vim 7.3, though